# How to convert python np.array to cv2 image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Following code:

```
img = np.array([[[1,2,4]]])
cv2.subtract(img, tuple([1.0]))
```

Results in error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0)
> C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-nxx381if\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:671:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) type2 == CV_64F && (sz2.height == 1 ||
> sz2.height == 4) in function 'cv::arithm_op'

If I change the img to:

```
img = np.array([[[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4]]])
```

Then it works correctly

In my case I have images of different sizes mono and color and I want to subtract constant value with saturation. The Shapes are HxWx1 or HxWx3 (different datatypes)
How to correctly use cv2.subtract for such cases ?

Edit:
I would like to keep high performance and avoid to allocate temporary arrays / types conversions

Comment: What "I want to subtract constant value with saturation" means? For color image, colorspace are you using? Also, in grayscale you have just one channel, so what are you meaning as saturation?

Comment: @iGian - I have constant value e.g: 3 and I want to subtract it from all channels. The value is equal for all channels. I want to use saturation arithmetic so e.g. for uint8: 2 - 3 = 0 or 250 + 10 = 255.

Comment: Does this work for you? `img = (img + 99).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: No, it does not saturate values: `img = np.array([[[200,201,202]]], dtype='uint8')
img = (img+100).astype(np.uint8)` results in: [[44 45 46]]. Correct answer is: [[255 255 255]]

Comment: Try clipping: `img_rgb = np.clip((img_rgb + 200), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`.

Comment: Yes but then it requires: 1. convert to wider type, 2. Add, 3. CLip, 4. Convert back to source type. OpenCV do it in a single iteration so it is several times faster. I have found that my opencv code doesn't work only for 2 input shapes: `(1,1,2)` and `(1,1,3)`. It is very unlikely to process such image, but since it is generic code user can provide such a strange image.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract a constant value from a numpy array:

```
img = np.array([[[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,4]]])
img_new=img-1
```

or if you want to use cv2.substract:

```
constant = 3
img_new_2=cv2.subtract(img, constant*np.ones(img.shape).astype(type(img[0,0,0])))
```

edit:
if you want to show this image using opencv you have to convert it to a valid type.

```
cv2.imshow("window", img_new_2.astype(np.int8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The first example is without saturation for dtype uint8. The second one (i suppose) will be time consuming because it needs to allocate temporary array. I would like to keep high performance.

Comment: work with wider data types, finally `numpy.clip` and narrow